# How to Mock PrimeNg MenuItem commend event in jest angular

Tags: angular, ts-jest, jest-fetch-mock

I try to mock PrimeNg MenuItem commend event but its not cover in coverage report.Can anyone please help me to write Jest unit test for 'command' (primeNg Click Event) in primeNg menu. I have already covered sortColumnsUp function with a test case.. but still below line showing as not covered.

How to cover that statement in jest coverage report.............

This is my code

```
  this.itemsWithdraw = [
    {
      label:'Withdraw Applicant',
      icon:'pi pi-fw pi-pencil',
      command: e => this.viewApplicantWithdraw(this.selectedGridMenuItem.reqTpsReferenceId),
      disabled: this.sharedService.isMspUser(),
     },

     {
      label:'History',
      icon:'pi pi-eye',
      command: e => this.getRequisitionSubmissionStatusHistoryById(this.selectedGridMenuItem.submissionId),
     }

  ];
```

Comment: Can you add the spec.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer ...

```
        let viewApplicantWithdrawspy= jest.spyOn(ApplicantSubmissionSearchComponent.prototype as any, 'viewApplicantWithdraw').mockReturnValue(true);
    let getRequisitionSubmissionStatusHistoryByIdspy= jest.spyOn(ApplicantSubmissionSearchComponent.prototype as any, 'getRequisitionSubmissionStatusHistoryById').mockReturnValue(true);
    this.selectedGridMenuItem={reqTpsReferenceId:1,submissionId:2,appTpsReferenceId: 3, submissionReferenceId: 4,applicantId:5,companyId:6}
    let isMspUserSpy = jest.spyOn(sharedServiceMock, 'isMspUser').mockReturnValue(true);

    this.itemsWithdrawMock = [
      {
        label:'Withdraw Applicant',
        icon:'pi pi-fw pi-pencil',
        command: jest.fn((event?: any) => {}),
        disabled: isMspUserSpy
       },

       {
        label:'History',
        icon:'pi pi-eye',
        command: jest.fn((event?: any) => {})
       }

    ];
    this.itemsWithdraw[0].command();
    this.itemsWithdraw[1].command();
  expect(viewApplicantWithdrawspy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1);
  expect(getRequisitionSubmissionStatusHistoryByIdspy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(2)
      expect(isMspUserSpy).toBeCalled();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).